# angular material .textarea don't update follow variable

Tags: angular, angular-material

> I tried to upload the Textfile into Textarea and edit it, but whenever I type and then upload it. Textarea will not update the contents of the files from the textfile.
> if you  write into textarea defore upload .txt data in file not show.
> file.js

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

/**
 * @title Input with a clear button
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'input-clearable-example',
  templateUrl: './input-clearable-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-clearable-example.css'],
})
export class InputClearableExample {
   @ViewChild("clrInput", { static: false }) clr: ElementRef;

  constructor() {}
 textArea: any;
 row=15

  onChange(value) {
    this.textArea = value
    console.log(this.textArea)
  }
  //upload
  onFileSelect(event) {
    const selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const text = reader.result.toString().trim();

      if (this.textArea === undefined) 
      {
        this.onChange(text)
      } 
      else 
      {
        var value=this.textArea + "\n" + text;
        this.onChange(value)
      }
      
    };
    this.clr.nativeElement.value = "";
    reader.readAsText(selectedFile);
  }



  ngOnInit() {

  }
}

> file.html
```

```html
<input
  type="file"
  id="file-button-id"
  accept=".txt"
  (change)="onFileSelect($event)"
  #clrInput
/>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <textarea matInput  rows="{{row}}" (keyup)="onChange($event.target.value)">
{{this.textArea}}</textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Jay, Angular was created mainly to relation variables in .ts with the .html. it's knowed as "binding" if you want to bind a variable you can use `[(ngModel)]="variable"` or ReactiveForms. See the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms) So you can forget this "javascript old fashioned style" of use (keyup)"

Answer (score 0):

One solution is The formControl:

```
export class InputClearableExample {
  @ViewChild("clrInput", { static: false }) clr: ElementRef;

  constructor() {}

  row = 15;
  textArea = new FormControl("");
  onChange(value: any) {
    this.textArea.setValue(value);
    console.log(this.textArea.value);
  }
  //upload
  onFileSelect(event: any) {
    const selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => {
      const text = reader.result ? reader.result.toString().trim() : "";

      var value = this.textArea.value + "\n" + text;
      this.onChange(value);
    };
    this.clr.nativeElement.value = "";
    reader.readAsText(selectedFile);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

and add `[formControl]="textArea"` to your textarea tag like this:

```
<input
  type="file"
  id="file-button-id"
  accept=".txt"
  (change)="onFileSelect($event)"
  #clrInput
/>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <textarea
    [formControl]="textArea"
    matInput
    rows="{{row}}"
    (keyup)="onChange($event.target.value)"
  >
</textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

You can remove text `{{textarea}}` between `<textarea></textarea>`tag.
here a [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wd787g?file=src/app/input-clearable-example.html) working example

Comment: Thank you.Can you tell me?.What is the cause?

Comment: @Antoineso, why you use the event (keyup) to only change the FormControl? it's **unnecessary**. To give value to a FormControl you should use [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue)

Answer (score 0):

(change)="onChange($event.target.value)"